# Passing function to other prototype

Tags: node.js, javascript-framework, javascript

I have below code

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/SashU/1/

```
var Callback = function(op) {
    this.callback = op.callback;
}

var Test = function (op) {
  for (var option in op) {
    if (!this[option]) this[option] = op[option];
  }

}

Test.prototype.init = function(bb) {
    console.log('aa = ' + this.aa);
    console.log('bb = ' + bb);

    if (bb < 3) {
        this.init(bb + 1);
    } else {
        this.callback;
    }
}

var finalCallback = function() {
    console.log('this is finalCallback');
}

var myCallback = new Callback({
    callback: finalCallback
});

var myTest = new Test({
    aa: 1,
    callback: myCallback
});

myTest.init(1);
```

**Line 19** didn't print `'this is finalCallback'` AT ALL because `this.callback;` got executed but it doesn't point to a function. But the below works:

```
myTest.init(1);
myCallback.callback();
```

I guess when passing `myCallback` to `myTest`, it didn't pass `finalCallback`??

Can someone help to explain this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here? Can you show a less abstract/confusing example? I don't get it...

Comment: lol.. it's a long story! There are just multiple modules I am using in node and they're confusing the heck out of me. I had to abstract the same flow to troubleshoot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you want to make this (use op.callback as function ):

```
var Callback = function (op) {
    this.callback = op.callback;
    return this.callback;
};
```

and functions should be invoked with `()`

```
 } else {
        this.callback();
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SashU/3/

[this is example where it can be used](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SashU/7/)

Comment: Ah got this. Look like when I do this `callback: myCallback`, the `callback` var only points to new `Callback` obj and not the `Callback.callback` prototype.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
var myTest = new Test({
    aa: 1,
    callback: myCallback.callback()
});
```

I assume this is the bit you mean. If not, please clarify what is not printing.

this doesn't work, because it is only a reference - an assignment.

```
  callback: myCallback
```

this is what executes it ()

so:

```
callback: myCallback.callback;
```

then:

```
this.callback();
```

I apologize if I am not succinct enough. I hope I am understanding what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks. Totally got it now.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you're not even trying to invoke `this.callback` on line 19. Invoke it with parentheses.

Even then, it doesn't work. When you do `var myTest = new Test({
    aa: 1,
    callback: myCallback
});`, myCallBack isn't a function; it's an object with a property `callback`. Change line 19's `this.callback` to `this.callback.callback()` to invoke that function. One line 19, `this.callback` is an instance of Callback—an object with a property `callback` that *is* a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/SashU/4/ shows a working example.